# Apostrophe comma not shown when use Holden font

Tags: fontspec

In normal font e.g default computer modern font apostrophe comma is appeared in the output. But when I use Holden font by `\setmainfont{Holden}` apostrophe comma is not appeared in the output.

My code is -

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} % also loads tikz
\setmainfont{Holden}
\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw = Periwinkle,
                                  fill = SpringGreen}}

\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning, % for left=of, above=of etc.
  calc % for let syntax used in second example
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={inner sep=0},
  node distance=5mm
]
   \node [Black] (text){Vaijan's Honey};



  \path
    let
    \p1=(text.south west),
    \p2=(text.north east),
    \n1={\x2-\x1}, % width of text node
    \n2={\y2-\y1}  % height of text node
    in
% in all of the below some fraction of \n1 or \n2 is used to define the width of the ornaments
% set width of these ornaments to half the text node's width
   node [anchor=north] (below) at (text.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.5*\n1,symmetry=c]{69}}
   node [anchor=south] (above) at (text.north) {\pgfornament[width=0.5*\n1]{69}}



% use \n2 for ornament width here
   node [rotate=-90, left=of text, anchor=north] (left)  {\pgfornament[width=\n2]{46}}
   node [rotate=90, right=of text, anchor=north] (right) {\pgfornament[width=\n2]{46}}
% and \n1 here
   node [above=of above] (top)    {\pgfornament[width=\n1]{71}}
   node [below=of below] (bottom) {\pgfornament[width=\n1,symmetry=h]{71}}
%   node [anchor=north] (top) at (text.north)   {\pgfornament[width=\n1]{71}}
%   node [anchor=south] (bottom) at (text.south) {\pgfornament[width=\n1,symmetry=h]{71}}
% and 25% of width for the corner ornaments
   node [anchor=north west] at (top.north -| left.south)  {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1]{63}}
   node [anchor=north east] at (top.north -| right.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=v]{63}}
   node [anchor=south west] at (bottom.south -| left.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=h]{63}}
   node [anchor=south east] at (bottom.south -| right.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=c]{63}}; % <- note the \path doesn't end until here

   % draw frame
  \draw [Blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);

  \vspace{2cm};
  \node [anchor=south] (bellowaddress1) at (below.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.10*\textwidth]{88}};
  \setmainfont{Linux Biolinum O}
  \tiny
  \node [Brown, below, align=center] (bellowaddress3) at (bellowaddress1.south) {Md.Al-Helal, CSE, DU\\ 01515611989};
  \node [anchor=south, below] (bellowaddress2) at (bellowaddress3.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.10*\textwidth]{88}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the mapping is not completely correct for this font. The log shows:

```
Missing character: There is no ’ in font [Holden.otf]/OT:mapping=tex-text;!
```

However, the character is present, as can be seen in FontForge:

[image]

FontForge shows the name of the character, `"quotesingle"`. This can be used for the macro `\XeTeXglyphindex` to find the index number, which can be used to print the character:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Holden.otf}
\begin{document}
The apostrophe is at position: \the\XeTeXglyphindex"quotesingle"

Printed: \XeTeXglyph83
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that here the `.otf` font is used, but it works the same for the `.ttf` version.

Applied to your MWE:

```
\node [Black] (text){Vaijan\XeTeXglyph83 s Honey};
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Fonts are loaded by default with `Ligatures=TeX`. This feature remaps `'` into U+2019, but apparently the Holden font has no glyph at that slot. To the contrary, its apostrophe at the standard ASCII position is curly.

Just load the font without `Ligatures=TeX`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} % also loads tikz


\newfontface{\holdenfont}{Holden}[
  Path=./,
  Extension=.otf,
  Ligatures=,
]

\tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw = Periwinkle,
                                  fill = SpringGreen}}

\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning, % for left=of, above=of etc.
  calc % for let syntax used in second example
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={inner sep=0},
  node distance=5mm
]
   \node [Black] (text){\holdenfont Vaijan's Honey};



  \path
    let
    \p1=(text.south west),
    \p2=(text.north east),
    \n1={\x2-\x1}, % width of text node
    \n2={\y2-\y1}  % height of text node
    in
% in all of the below some fraction of \n1 or \n2 is used to define the width of the ornaments
% set width of these ornaments to half the text node's width
   node [anchor=north] (below) at (text.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.5*\n1,symmetry=c]{69}}
   node [anchor=south] (above) at (text.north) {\pgfornament[width=0.5*\n1]{69}}



% use \n2 for ornament width here
   node [rotate=-90, left=of text, anchor=north] (left)  {\pgfornament[width=\n2]{46}}
   node [rotate=90, right=of text, anchor=north] (right) {\pgfornament[width=\n2]{46}}
% and \n1 here
   node [above=of above] (top)    {\pgfornament[width=\n1]{71}}
   node [below=of below] (bottom) {\pgfornament[width=\n1,symmetry=h]{71}}
%   node [anchor=north] (top) at (text.north)   {\pgfornament[width=\n1]{71}}
%   node [anchor=south] (bottom) at (text.south) {\pgfornament[width=\n1,symmetry=h]{71}}
% and 25% of width for the corner ornaments
   node [anchor=north west] at (top.north -| left.south)  {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1]{63}}
   node [anchor=north east] at (top.north -| right.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=v]{63}}
   node [anchor=south west] at (bottom.south -| left.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=h]{63}}
   node [anchor=south east] at (bottom.south -| right.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.25*\n1,symmetry=c]{63}}; % <- note the \path doesn't end until here

   % draw frame
  \draw [Blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);

  \vspace{2cm};
  \node [anchor=south] (bellowaddress1) at (below.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.10*\textwidth]{88}};
  \setmainfont{Linux Biolinum O}
  \tiny
  \node [Brown, below, align=center] (bellowaddress3) at (bellowaddress1.south) {Md.Al-Helal, CSE, DU\\ 01515611989};
  \node [anchor=south, below] (bellowaddress2) at (bellowaddress3.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.10*\textwidth]{88}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I loaded it not as the main font and specified path and extension just to adapt to my setup (I surely don't want that font clobbering my system fonts ).

[image]